# Docker run via subprocess

Tags: docker, subprocess

Ok, I am firing off some docker run commands via subprocess calls (in a GUI). The call looks like this:

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = a.stdout.decode().split("\n")
```

The process living in the docker container would log to the stdout and I thought I could then fetch my logging messages. I am using the docker run -a command, as in

```
/usr/bin/docker run --rm  -a stdout xxxx/pyrisk:latest python prices.py
```

Comment: And does this work ?

Using Python 3.7 you should use 'catch_output=True' to collect stdout, stderr. Note this comes as a byte string, so you will need to str() the results.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use docker.py library instead of directly calling docker commands via subprocess.
See more here: https://github.com/docker/docker-py

Your case would look like:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
stdout = client.containers.run(image="xxxx/pyrisk:latest",command="python prices.py", remove=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, docker.py / docker-py does not support the "--gpu=" command-line argument. Hence it's necessary to run it via a subprocess.

Comment: Or there's python_on_whales: https://github.com/gabrieldemarmiesse/python-on-whales